# $ followed by a char in command line argument in C

Tags: c, command-line

I just wrote a program in c language which uses command line arguments and i tried to print the first argument. when i execute program with following command

```
./a.out $23
```

and try to print the first argument using the below code

```
printf("%s", argv[1]);
```

the output is just

```
3
```

Am i missing something here, that command line arguments are treated differently if some special characters are present. can some one explain this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` character.

Try this:

```
./a.out \$23
```

Answer (score 4):

Presumably the `$2` is being treated as a shell variable. Try escaping the dollar sign:

```
./a.out \$23
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to "inhibit" you argument like this:

```
./a.out \$23
```

Some characters are interpreted by the shell. These characters include the following:

- `\` Which inhibits (escapes) the character just behind it (usefull for space, tabs or in your case)
- `*` Which represents any single character or character strings
- `$` Which represents a variable (in your case, the shell understands the variable $23, not the string "$23")
- `||` or `|` Which allows a resolution in your command or to pipe your command
- `&&` or `&` Which allows combination of commands or which allows the use of job control
- `"` Which allows the shell to delimit a character string
- `'` Which allows the shell to not interpret a character string with special characters
- `;` Which delimits commands
- `` ` ``  Which interprets the command enclosed by two of these and returns the command's output

Answer (score 1):

The shell treats `$23` as the positional parameter `$2` followed by the literal character 3. To pass the string "$23", do either

```
./a.out \$23
```

or

```
./a.out '$23'
```

To pass the shell's 23rd positional parameter (unlikely, but possible), you would write

```
./a.out ${23}
```